# How to split data in retrofit to add horizontal progressBar in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, retrofit

I want to add horizontal progressBar instead of circle progressBar so I have to split data of images list that i want to post it  how I can do it

this is my code progressBar here is not horizontal , Thanks in advance

```
  public void postImages() {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadedImagesList.size(); i++) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            uploadedImagesList.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            encode.add(encoded);
        }
        submitImage.setEnabled(false);
        PowerModel powerModel = new PowerModel();
        powerModel.setPowerOfWingsPhotos(encode);
        if (encode.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.fields_empty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                    show();
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CheckInternetConnection connectionCheck = new CheckInternetConnection(getContext());
        if (connectionCheck.haveNetworkConnection()) {
            ApiCallbacks apiCallbacks = ApiClient.getClient(getContext()).create(ApiCallbacks.class);
            retrofit2.Call<Void> call = apiCallbacks.postPowerImages(ApiClient.BASE_URL + "promoters/upload_power_of_wings_photos/" + SharedSession2.getJcpId(getContext()), powerModel, SharedSession.getPromoterId(getContext()), SharedSession.getAccessToken(getContext()), SharedSession2.getBranch_ID(getContext()));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                        uploadedImagesList.clear();
                        encode.clear();
                        uploadImagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                                show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        submitImage.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    submitImage.setEnabled(true)}
            });
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            submitImage.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.check_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                    show();
        }
    }
```